# Vim has started adding commas unnecessary places

Tags: debugging

When I use `:w` to save my JSON file, vim automatically adds some commas
at syntactically significant (?) places. 
It does not happen when I use `:x` or `ZZ`.  This started today. 
I did not change anything about vim (expect just tab space).

Here’s an animated demonstration:
[image]

Do you have any suggestions? I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Linter or plugin or both.

Comment: Most likely it is some plugin. You _may_ be able to identify the guilty by executing `autocmd BufWritePre`. If not [debug your vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file).

Comment: You can try `:Xverbose w` where X is 9, 12 or 15 (increasing numbers provide further levels of detail...sometimes too much detail thus start lower and then go higher if necessary) If that doesn't lead you to the answer then follow the link Ralf provided.

Comment: I've learned a lot while reading about `:autocmd` and `:verbose`. Debugging your `vimrc` looks like a great post.  Thank you very much.